How to Smoothen Hands and Add Fingernails to Avaturn Avatar in Blender for Unity VR Project
I created my avatar with Avaturn (V2) and now I want to make it more realistic with Blender. I want to smoothen the hands in Blender (current state in screenshot) and add fingernails. Unfortunately I can only find tutorials on how to create hands from scratch, but not how to customise them. I don't know how to smoothen the hands and add the fingernails or how to begin. Later I want to import the avatar into Unity for my VR project. I appreciate any help, I am still very new to Blender.



It's gonna be pretty rare that you're gonna find a tutorial that will tell you how to do exactly every thing you want to do, without including any parts you don't need. You have to start learning how to take what you can from tutorials and leave what you don't need. If at that point you're still lost you should just go through some beginner tutorials and learn the basics before trying to make a whole VR project.

All this to say, the tutorial that tells you how to "smooth a hand and add fingernails" is the same as a tutorial that shows you how to make a hand, except without all the parts that aren't about smoothing a hand and adding fingernails. Add a subsurf modifier to smooth it. Duplicate the model and extract the fingernail geo to add fingernails. And so on.
